# QT MYSQL QThread

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5

У меня есть два класса: `checkMessage` унаследованный от `QThread` и основной класс-форма `mainwindow` унаследованный от `QWidget`. В первом классе раз в несколько секунд идет проверка и добавление данных из бд в вектор. А из основного класса идет добавление новых данных в бд при нажитии кнопки. Но проблема когда одновременно два потока срабатывают в одно время появляется ошибка:

> Lost connection to MySQL server during query QMYSQL: Unable to execute query

И программа вылетает.

Функция проверки данных в классе `checkMessage`

```
QVector<QString> vectorMessages;
void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        query.exec("SELECT `message` FROM `messages`");
        vectorMessages.clear();
        while(query.next())
        {
            vectorMessages.push_back(query.value(0).toString() + "\n");
            //message+= query.value(0).toString() + "\n";

        }
        emit sendUpdate(); //  слот в главном потоке
        Sleep(1500);

    }
}
```

Функция добавления данных в форме:

```
QString message = ui->text_message->toPlainText();
query.prepare("INSERT INTO `messages`(`message`) VALUES (:mess)");
query.bindValue(":mess",message);
qDebug() << query.exec();
```

Comment: c QThread так не работают. Заведите таймер на полторы секунды, по сигналу от таймера кладите задачу получения данных из БД в QThreadPool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А собственно зачем вам второй поток? SELECT можно делать по таймеру. В этом случае не возникнет проблем с многопоточностью. Если результат SELECT очень большой, было бы логично выполнять отдельным потоком все операции с БД. Для этого можно сделать вот такой класс.

```
class QDb : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QDb(QObject *parent):QObject(parent){инициализация БД}
public slots:
    void insert(QString str){вставка значения}
    void select(){заполнение вектора};
signals:
    sendUpdate();
};

QDb *db = new QDb();
QThread thread* = new QThread();
db->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
```

Теперь все действия с БД будут выполнять в отдельном потоке и ошибок не будет. Вызывать select() можно по сигналу от таймера, а insert(QString str) по сигналу от кнопки.